# How to get App Limits working?

Tags: iphone, parental-controls, screen-time

I'd like so set a 6 hour App Limit for a specific apps.  However, after setting the limit, the app is immediately limited.  This is well before the 6 hours runs out.   Thoughts on how to get app limits working?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "I set the app limit to 6 hours but the app is still limited" -> Isn't this what you want? Or is the problem that the app is not accessible even before the 6 hours run out?

Comment: Your edit is even more confusing than the original version.

Comment: Did you use the app for any amount of time *prior* to setting the limit?  If so, when and for how long?

Comment: Your question lacks clarity, I cannot seem to understand what you are trying to do exactly. Here are some questions for you to answer, please include that as clarifications in the question. What are you trying to achieve exactly? What isn't working as you expect it to work? What do you expect? What do you see instead?

Comment: Let’s see whether somebody has an idea. I’m curios though: If you set a limit like that, does it work correctly the next day?

Comment: @Allan no, it is instantly blocked.

Comment: @Thinkr  When I set the app limit to 6 hours and it instantly blocks the app thus not granting the desired 6 hours.  It simply isn't working but I could speculate (similar to cascading style sheets) it has some other block going on that Im not aware of such as a category limit.

Comment: Instead of guessing, why not check the category limits?  Post this info so we can get a clearer picture.

Comment: @JStark Okay. Blocking the app instantly after you've set the limit is because you've already spent the 6 hours that day.

Comment: @Allan How do you export all the category limits?  I highlighted all the rows but copy-paste didn't copy the list?

Comment: @Thinkr that is the expected behavior, but we haven't used the app at all for the day.  Hence the reason for this inquiry.

Comment: Okay. Have you tried setting this limit with another app? Are you setting limits for apps or for categories? Maybe you have both (as Allan mentioned)? Also, you could not copy/paste, you have to take a screenshot ([instructions for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201361), [instructions for iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT210781), [instructions for iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT200289)). Also, are you using a Mac, and iPad or and iPhone?